# How to change value inside function

Tags: python, loops

Very new to coding. I'm trying to learn myself Python by doing a little project I came up with. I realize this will be a slow process, but I just had a question about loops.

This is what I'm trying to do:

-The user inputs a list of numbers, and if a number in the list is more than 360, the function will subtract 360 from it until it is below 360.

-Once it's below 360:

- If it's above 270, it will subtract the number from 360.
- If it's above 180, it will subtract 180 from the number.
- If it's above 90, it will subtract the number from 180.

-It should then print the values. If this process sounds familiar, I'm trying to convert an azimuth to a bearing. Right now I'm just focused on getting the numerical value, then I'll add the direction.

This is my code:

```
    def bearing(x):
        for i in range(len(x)):
            while x[i]>=360:
                x[i]-=360
            if x[i]>270:
                x[i]==360-x[i]
            elif x[i]>180:
                x[i]-=180
            elif x[i]>90:
                x[i]==180-x[i]
        print (x)
```

The while loop works fine, but it stops there. I'm not sure if my indenting is wrong, or I'm using the wrong commands, but any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The double equal `==` is for checking values.  Assignment is the single equal `=` .  So `x[i] == 360-x[i]` should be `x[i] = 360-x[i]`

Comment: Instead of subtracting until it's below 360, use the modulus operator `%`

Comment: Try adding an else condition in the end and print something in that block. I believe none of the condition is getting satisfied.

Comment: @JohnColeman  On input 91, your solution returns 1 when he wants 89 according to his written requirements.

Comment: @JohnColeman After some more reading, it sounds like you could do 
`[(az % 90) if az % 180 < 90 else 90 - (az%90) for az in x]`

Comment: If you're new to coding, no matter which language, I suggest you have a look at some tutorials. Will be a big help to learn it right (and faster than in your way). Good luck!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using assignment (`=`) you're using comparison (`==`). Try this:

```
def bearing(x):
    for i in range(len(x)):
        while x[i]>=360:
            x[i]-=360
        if x[i]>270:
            x[i]=360-x[i]
        elif x[i]>180:
            x[i]-=180
        elif x[i]>90:
            x[i]=180-x[i]
    print (x)
```

You may also shorten the while loop into a single `% 360`.

This is a cleaner function that does the same:

```
def bearing(x):
    for i, v in enumerate(x):
        v = v % 360
        if v > 270:
            v = 360-v
        elif v > 180:
            v -= 180
        elif v > 90:
            v = 180-v
        x[i] = v
    print (x)
```

Comment: Thank you, this fixed the original. I'm assuming the v in enumerate() works the same as the x[i], and you replaced all the values in the list at the end?

Comment: Exactly. Keep in mind I have changed the last one from `90-v` to `180-v` as your request was to subtract from 180.

Comment: Hi @quesadyllan, if this or any answer has solved your question please consider accepting it by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to use `range(len(x))`.  Instead, you can iterate over the elements in `x` explicitly.

```
def bearing(x):
    for item in x:
        item = item % 360 #This gets the remainder of dividing item by 360
        if item > 270:
            print(360 - item)
        elif item > 180:
            print(item - 180)
        elif item > 90:
            print(180 - item)
        else:
            print(item)
```

Comment: Thank you, it all checks out. I'm still trying to get used to forming the logic on my own but looking at this makes sense.

Comment: This line `print(180 - item):` generate invalid syntax

Comment: oops, stray punctuation

Answer (score 0):

You may or may not be familiar with the modulus operator (`%`). What that does is return the remainder from division, which is basically caffeinated subtraction anyway. For example, `5 % 3` would return `2` since `5 / 3 == 1 remainder 2`. Hopefully you can see how `user_input % 360` would take care of your initial subtraction to `< 360`.

Translating this to a list of numbers: `list_below_360 = [x % 360 for x in user_input_list]`.

So now, let's assume we have properly formatted user input that is a list of integers all below 360.

```
for i in range(len(list_below_360)):
    if list_below_360[i] > 270:
        list_below_360[i] = 360 - list_below_360[i]
        #notice the use of a single equals sign here,
        #a double equals sign does comparison, not assignment
    elif list_below_360[i] > 180:
        list_below_360[i] -= 180
    elif list_below_360[i] > 90:
        list_below_360[i] = 90 - list_below_360[i]
print(list_below_360)
```

Hope this helps.